# Can't Paint in Texture Paint

Tags: texture-painting

I have tried all the fixes I could find with no luck. Can someone take a peak at my blender file and help me figure out why I can't paint in Texture Paint?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10qybvIDgkR-VLeLwaWkIyVdXHQZHrfAR/view?usp=sharing
[image]

Comment: Do blend-exchange.com instead.

Comment: Hello and welcome, please add more details for your question. Like: did you create a new texture, paint settings, object, material settings and so on. the more, the better to help you

Answer (score 0):

In your active brush a completely black texture is enabled, so that every stroke has 0 effect. Just disable the texture in brush options.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for my problem!